# Jquery animation on changing Boostrap navbar

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I ve got the code attached, and I managed to change the navbar color and logo when I am scrolling down. However, I would like to have a transition when this change happens.

I tried with many transition options in CSS but no luck.

```
 <nav class="navbar  fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
          <img src="/assets/Intech Logo.png" height="54px" alt="" loading="lazy" />
        </a>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

JQuery

```
$(function () { 
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 1) { 
            $('.navbar .navbar-brand img').attr('src','/assets/PNG White Print.png');
            $('.navbar').addClass('scrolled')


        }
        if ($(this).scrollTop() < 1) { 
            $('.navbar .navbar-brand img').attr('src','/assets/Intech Logo.png');
            $('.navbar').removeClass('scrolled')
        }
    })
});
```

```
.navbar{
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #1c003b , #5216aa);
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.scrolled{

  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #15002d , #3e1181);
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  transition: 0.25s;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;// not working

}
```

Any help is welcomed. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Sample with jQuery

$(window).scroll(function(){
   var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
   if(scroll < 400){
       $('.fixed-top').css('background', 'rgba(71,71,71,1)');
   } else{
      $('.fixed-top').css('background', '#fcfcfc');
   }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
 
 <nav class="navbar fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
          <img src="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/assets/img/bootstrap-icons.png" height="54px" alt="" loading="lazy" />
        </a>
      </div>
    </nav>
    
    <!-- HTML CODES HERE -->
   <h1 style="margin-top: 90px;"> Write your html codes here and It would work.</h1>
    
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js">
 </script>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.